# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3: "The 'XamlDiagnosticsPackage' package did not load correctly" when going to debug a WPF or Universal App

Tags: wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

constantly followed by Visual Studio crash ('Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working....'):

[image: failed to load]
[image: stopped working]

No way to debug any WPF or Universal app at all.

Repairing Visual Studio **does not help** (tried twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml showed, that "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified".

Searching for Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.dll produced no results - that DLL appeared to be simply missing on my laptop.

The crash problem solved by copying the whole contents of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies from another (stable) machine. At least, I'm now able to debug!

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, would you please mark it as the answer? So it would be helpful for other community members who meet the same issue as yours. Thanks for your sharing:)